# Android DynamoDB connection

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

So we are trying to make a simple test app by hard coding a way of adding a row into our DynamoDB database and from following the short description of how to in the SDK example we get this.

So in our main activity we create the credentialsProvider and create our class that was derived from AsyncTask and then run it.

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "us-east-1:<Stuff>", // Identity Pool ID
                Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
        );
        runMapper myMapper = new runMapper(credentialsProvider);
        myMapper.execute();
```

In the AsyncTask we set up the client and the mapper and then try to save it.

```
public class runMapper extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;

    public runMapper(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentials){
        credentialsProvider = credentials;
    }
    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... args) {

        AmazonDynamoDB ddbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddbClient);

        Vocab test = new Vocab();
        test.setEnglish("Apple");
        test.setLanguage("Greek");
        test.setEquivalent("Milo");

        mapper.save(test);
        return "yay";
    }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
```

}

And our class that represents our table is as follows.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Vocab_Test")
public class Vocab {
    private String English;
    private String Language;
    private String Equivalent;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "English")
    public String getEnglish() {
        return English;
    }
    public void setEnglish(String s){
        this.English = s;
    }

    @DynamoDBIndexHashKey (attributeName = "Language")
    String getLanguage(){
        return Language;
    }
    public void setLanguage(String s){
        this.Language = s;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Equivalent")
    public String getEquivalent(){
        return Equivalent;
    }
    public void setEquivalent(String s){
        this.Equivalent = s;
    }

}
```

The error we get is this and we are unsure how to proceed or what is causing the error exactly.

```
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.amazon.mysampleapp, PID: 26641
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: <Number>)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:709)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:385)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:196)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3257)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:965)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.doUpdateItem(DynamoDBMapper.java:1173)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$2.executeLowLevelRequest(DynamoDBMapper.java:873)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.execute(DynamoDBMapper.java:1056)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:904)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:688)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.Other.runMapper.doInBackground(runMapper.java:31)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.Other.runMapper.doInBackground(runMapper.java:12)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.amazon.mysampleapp, PID: 26641
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: <Number>)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:709)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:385)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:196)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3257)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:965)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.doUpdateItem(DynamoDBMapper.java:1173)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$2.executeLowLevelRequest(DynamoDBMapper.java:873)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.execute(DynamoDBMapper.java:1056)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:904)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:688)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.Other.runMapper.doInBackground(runMapper.java:31)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.Other.runMapper.doInBackground(runMapper.java:12)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
11-08 14:51:05.201 26641-26701/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: `com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: <Number>)` is the error, check your schema, and attribute definitions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the DynamoDB table you created has a different schema. A few things you can check.

- Please double check your table "Vocab_Test" in the console and make sure it has a String attribute "English" as its hash key.
- When you use DynamoDBIndexHashKey, you need to tell the mapper the index name via [globalSecondaryIndexName](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBIndexHashKey.html#globalSecondaryIndexName()). This shouldn't cause any issue to save data, but you won't be able to query with this index.

For more information, please see the getting started guide [Store and Query App Data in DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/getting-started-store-query-app-data.html).